# Conditional formatting not working with UITableView Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm thinking that this is an issue with reusing cells but I can't figure this out and would appreciate some additional eyes on it. I have a uitableviewcell subclass that compares two values, if one value is higher it changes the cell background to red, else it changes it to white. As I scroll, some cells are white that should be red and vice versa.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     tut_MaintListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"maintCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


// Configure the cell...

MaintItem *mItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


[cell configureCellForEntry:mItem sendCar:self.carDetail];


return cell;
}
```

UITableViewCell Subclass

```
- (void)configureCellForEntry:(MaintItem *)mItem sendCar:(Car *)carDetails
{
    self.itemLabel.text = [mItem valueForKey:@"item"];
    self.actionLabel.text = [mItem valueForKey:@"action"];
    self.engineLabel.text = [mItem valueForKey:@"engineCode"];
    self.maintIDLabel.text = [[mItem valueForKey:@"maintID" ]stringValue];


// Grab the mileages recorded in the log for this maint item and turn it into a sorted array
NSArray *result = [[mItem.toLog valueForKey:@"mileage"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"" ascending:YES]]];

// Determine mileage of next service
NSString *nextServiceMileage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",  [mItem.intMileage intValue] + [[result lastObject] intValue]];

nextServiceMileageNS = @([nextServiceMileage intValue]);


if ([mItem.frequencyID isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]])
{
           NSString *timing = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %@ Once at %@ miles or %@ months", [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"frequencyID"], [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"intMileage"], [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"intMonth"]];
    NSString *howOften = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %@", timing];
    self.howOftenLabel.text = howOften;

    if (carDetails.mileage > nextServiceMileageNS)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

}

else if ([mItem.frequencyID isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]])

{
    NSString *timing = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %@ Every %@ miles or %@ months, due at %@ ", [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"frequencyID"], [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"intMileage"], [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"intMonth"], nextServiceMileage];
    NSString *howOften = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %@", timing];
    self.howOftenLabel.text = howOften;

    if (carDetails.mileage > nextServiceMileageNS)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

}

else

{
    NSString *howOften = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" %@", [mItem valueForKeyPath:@"frequencyID"]];
    self.howOftenLabel.text = howOften;
}


}
```

Comment: your cell MUST have a default value for background color and only change the color under certain condition. Otherwise when scrolling up and down your cell's order will be mixed up.

Comment: `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` be the first line of your configure cell for entry method and try again

Comment: Hi Panayot, I just tried that and still get same results of incorrect background colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was comparing two NSnumber objects in the if statement. I changed
`if (carDetails.mileage > nextServiceMileageNS)`to `if ([carDetails.mileage intvalue] > [nextServiceMileageNS intvalue])` and now it worked correctly. The way the random background were applied it seemed to be a cell reuse issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is: you have to set the backgroundColor in the else part too. Better solution would be,

```
UIView *backgroundView;

if (condition_1) {

    backgroundView = [UIView new];
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

} else if (condition_2) {

    backgroundView = [UIView new];
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

} else {

    // here you can set or leave it.
}

[self setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

hope it will work for you...

Comment: Hi Goppinath, I added that but I still get the same results when scrolling.